# C# opening other files in other folders

Tags: c#

So i have been trying to figure this little bit out how can i open a folder after the root folder that the program is in. What I'm looking for is something like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Watcher
{

   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Process.Start("..\this.txt");
    }
 }
```

From what im use to on other languages is that ..\ means forward from root folder but it doesn't seem to work any one got an idea how to get it to work?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Does `this.txt` exist in the expected location?  Is it able to start as a process?  Does it work if you use the absolute path for that file?

Comment: @David if i am using the "..\this.txt" i give me and error of The system cannot find the file specified. but i put this.txt into the same folder as the .exe and use Process.Start("this.txt") it will work

Comment: The .. means one level up from current folder, not forward from the root folder.

Comment: @user3448117: How about a forward-slash instead of a back-slash?  Also try using `Path.Combine()` or other `Path` utilities to make it less platform-dependant.

Answer (score 2):

\t is tab. Try use "..\\this.txt".

Comment: Nice pick up. Can also try `Process.Start(@"..\this.txt");`